# Get the private keys of the Address with hard hat

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ethers.js, hardhat

during the node  start (hard hat) I'm able to read the accounts and private keys.

I don't understand how can I retrieve it again with hard hat console

`npx hardhat console`

I injected even web3 library but I'm able to retrieve only the addresses.

web3:
`await web3.eth.getAccounts()`

ethers.js

`[owner, addr1] = await ethers.getSigners()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private keys, even of unlocked accounts, are not shared over the [JSON-RPC API](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API).

Which means, you are not able to retrieve them using web3js, ethers.js, or any other wrapper of the API.

Comment: thanks petr, so I need to get the private keys when I start the node? I don't have any call (even from hard hat without RPC) ?

Comment: @foo_bar That's correct. If you want to import the private keys to the app, you need to retrieve them from the node manually - not over an API.

Comment: ok, and manually, only when the node starts? I can't find a seed or something like that with a "hard hat" core call?

Comment: @foo_bar Probably just at the node start. I just skimmed the hardhat docs but didn't find a way to get the keys during runtime.